# How do I check that list was initialized with 0 elements in it?

Tags: java, list, reflection

For example:

```
public List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and how can I check through reflection that this list is empty and not null?

```
for (final Field field : ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(clazz)) {
    if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
        // TODO check whether the list is empty.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Field.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)) to obtain the field value and then cast it to `List`:

```
List<?> l = (List<?>) Field.get(obj);
if (l == null || l.isEmpty()) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#isEmpty()) in the interface `List`. You can use that method in your if condition as in below.

```
 if  (list==null||list.isEmpty) {
    //TODO if the list is empty
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to check weather it is null and empty.

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    Field fields[] = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        try {
            Object value = field.get(this);
            if (value != null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {        
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```